# How do I set up a tsconfig file for a client project using threads?

Tags: typescript, multithreading, browser, tsconfig

I want to create a program that runs in the browser and uses [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) or [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) to create threads.
I've had success in JavaScript, but not TypeScript.

By default TypeScript gives me access to the DOM, but not to [SharedWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorkerGlobalScope).  So it's perfect for my main thread, but my worker threads can't access their message queues and similar resources.

I know about the [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) setting in tsconfig.json.  That would allow me to fix the libraries for my code that runs in the worker threads.  But it would break the code that needs to access the dom.  lib applies to the entire project.  Is there a way to change the libraries for just a single file or directory?

How do people normally handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work.  I don't like this answer, but at least it got my program to run.

In `tsconfig.json` I **added** `WebWorker` to the end of `"lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "WebWorker"],`.  Normally you would **replace** `DOM` with `WebWorker`.

In the main thread I could write code as normal.  In a `SharedWorker` I would write

```
const GLOBAL = self as unknown as SharedWorkerGlobalScope;
```

at the top of the file, and things like

```
GLOBAL.onconnect = (event) => {
```

in the file.

I should not have to write `GLOBAL.` every time.  And this setup also fails to catch certain mistakes.  For the most part this works, but it feels like a hack.  I hope someone can offer a better way to use threads in TypeScript.